# Выбрать 8 случайных карт из 56

Tags: php, случайные-числа

Есть колода карт (56 штук)
В начале игры, человеку даётся 8 карт путём рандома

```
$all_cards = range(1, 56);
$first_pool = rand($all_cards, 2);
echo $first_pool;
```

Браузер выдаёт ошибку

> Warning: rand() expects parameter 1 to be long, array given in ?C:\OSPanel\domains\Rokki\index.php on line 19

Что делать? Как реализовать рандомную раздачу карт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо

```
$first_pool = rand($all_cards, 2);
```

надо использовать

```
$first_pool = rand(1, 56);
```

так как функция `rand()` определена как

```
int rand ( int $min , int $max )
```

Но это не то, что вы хотите.

Вместо того использыйте функцию `shuffle()` чтобы стасовать карты, и потом выберите первые `8` из них:

```
$all_cards= range(1, 56);
shuffle($all_cards);
$first_pool = array_slice($all_cards, 0, 8);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно, могу ли я поинтересоваться, как вывести все значения массива $first_pool?

Comment: `print_r($first_pool);`

Comment: Или `foreach ($first_pool as &$value) { print($value." "); }`